# My pygame code is running horribly slow, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

So I'm trying to make tetris in pygame, and it was running really slow. I isolated the function that draws everything and even that is running really slow, how can I fix this? (And by running I mean I get a black screen and the desired images just load slowly from the bottom over the course of several minutes.)

P.S. There are some unused variables because I was too lazy to comment them out, but I don't imagine a couple variables make a big difference

```
import random
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
win=pygame.display.set_mode((420, 840))
clock= pygame.time.Clock()

score= 0
level= 0
lines= 0
field= [[1]*10 for _ in range(22)]


run= True
play= True
setState= False
t= 48
frameCounter= 0
font= pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 30)

def drawWin():
        tempY= 40
        for y in range(2 ,22):
            tempX= 10
            for x in field[y]:
                if(x==1):
                    win.fill((255, 255, 255), (tempX, tempY, 40, 40))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (tempX, tempY, 40, 40), 5)
                tempX+=40
            tempY+=40
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (10, 40, 400, 800), 2)
        text= font.render('Score: '+ str(score)+ '\nLevel: '+ str(level), 1, (255, 255, 255))

while True:
    drawWin()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type== pygame.QUIT:
            break
    time.sleep(1)
    clock.tick(t)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: try adding `pygame.display.update()` to the end of your while loop & not sure what the `time.sleep(1)` is for

Comment: @Andy yep ur right about the update thing, cannot believe i forgot that, thanks. the sleep was just for testing.

Comment: The thing i am puzzled by here is the statement that "the desired images just load slowly from the bottom over the course of several minutes". Without the `update()` I can't see how anything showed on the screen at all !

Comment: @AdvaitM nw! That makes sense - have added my answer formally so we can close this Q (plus always up for SO rep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `pygame.display.update()` to the end of your while loop

I've had a similar issue running Pygame before :))

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix, forgot the update display command for pygame.

Comment: @RufusVS cant accept my own for 2 days, if the guy in the comments wants to add his own answer in the meantime ill accept that instead